# How to insert into a table using loop based on another select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query which returns some IDs.

```
SELECT GROUP_ID FROM GROUP_REQUEST_MAPPING WHERE REQUEST_TYPE_ID = 1
```

As a result I get this.

```
GROUP_ID
6
7
8
9
14
```

I have to loop through the IDs and then insert that many rows in another table.

```
INSERT INTO REQ_TASK VALUES(_,_,_,IDs)
```

How do I do that. I am new to sql. Thanks

Comment: You want to do this in SQL or from an application? How are you planning to get values for other columns of REQ_TASK table? Are they static for all the groupids?

Comment: in my stored procedure.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya I am getting other column values based on the input parameters of the stored procedure.

Comment: Are the other values(_,_,) in REQ_TASK VALUES(_,_,_,IDs) some constants or picked up from different table

Comment: @Kapil Yes some values are constant and some are from the input parameters of the SP.

Answer (score 4):

Directly use the constants or parameters with the select like below:

```
INSERT INTO REQ_TASK VALUES(_,_,_,IDs)
SELECT @param1,@param2,'xyz', GROUP_ID FROM GROUP_REQUEST_MAPPING WHERE REQUEST_TYPE_ID = 1
```

Here is a small example

```
 Create table #food
( item varchar(50))

insert into #food values 
('icecream'),
('sandwich'),
('Pasta'),
('FrenchFries'),
('Toast')
```

--Create another table #food_test

```
Create table #food_test
( item varchar(50),quantity int)

Insert into #food_test(item,quantity)
select item,10 from #food
```

Now check the value in  #food_test

```
select * from #food_test
```

Comment: Will this single statement of insert create 5 rows in the REQ_TASK table?

Comment: yes, if the SELECT GROUP_ID FROM GROUP_REQUEST_MAPPING WHERE REQUEST_TYPE_ID = 1 returns 5 rows then

Comment: You saved my day ! the answer really worked for me . just to be clear this statment actualy iterateed throgh the "list" the returns from the "select statment" ant isertets  value after value from the first Tbl to the second Tbl.

Comment: Now I'm looking to make sure that if i already have such a "key-value" pair in the 2nd table it won't insert it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
INSERT INTO REQ_TASK (col1, ...) 
SELECT GROUP_ID FROM GROUP_REQUEST_MAPPING 
WHERE REQUEST_TYPE_ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use your query to insert in another table via insert into statement as

```
USE MASTER

 Create table GROUP_REQUEST_MAPPING
( GROUP_ID int, REQUEST_TYPE_ID int)

insert into GROUP_REQUEST_MAPPING values 
(6,1),
(7,1),
(8,1),
(9,1),
(10,1)
Create table REQ_TASK (AMOUNT int, IDs int)
SELECT * FROM GROUP_REQUEST_MAPPING
SELECT * FROM REQ_TASK

INSERT INTO REQ_TASK (AMOUNT,IDs)
SELECT 10, GROUP_ID FROM GROUP_REQUEST_MAPPING WHERE REQUEST_TYPE_ID = 1

SELECT * FROM REQ_TASK

DROP TABLE REQ_TASK
DROP TABLE GROUP_REQUEST_MAPPING
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp